# Adding Stylesheet into XML document

Tags: java, css, xml

I want to add style sheet into XML document dynamically using JAVA, However i am getting an exception. My code snippet looks like:

```
final String xmlStr = "My XML tags in form of String here";

Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);  

String documen = addStylesheet( doc);

System.out.println(documen);

public static String addStylesheet(Document document)
{

     ProcessingInstruction pi = (ProcessingInstruction)    
     document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"my.stylesheet.xsl\"");


      document.appendChild((Node) pi);  

      return document.toString(); 
}
```

Exception thrown is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ProcessingInstructionImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.events.ProcessingInstruction
    at StringToDocumentToString.insertStylesheet(StringToDocumentToString.java:70)
    at StringToDocumentToString.main(StringToDocumentToString.java:27)
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong. thanks

Comment: Read your exception. Casting is what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at : http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/ProcessingInstructionImpl.html

It seems that there is a [ProcessingInstruction](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/w3c/dom/ProcessingInstruction.html) interface, other than Java's.

Comment: The thing is you are casting to the wrong Interface. Please review your code and your class cast exception and you will figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Yes I cast it to ProcessingInstructionImpl and my issue is fixed.